# build failed while building blenders goo engine cycle on windows 11

Tags: build, blender

I was building custom build of blender called "goo engine". While building it I got some error for cycle build. Here is the log part where the build failed, anyone knows how to solve it ?

```
Build FAILED.

C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\goo-engine\source\blender\editors\object\object_constraint.c(2214,43): warning C4100: 'con': unreferenced formal parameter [C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\source\blender\editors\object\bf_editor_object.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\goo-engine\intern\ghost\intern\GHOST_Wintab.cc(193,14): error C2397: conversion from 'int' to 'const unsigned __int64' requires a narrowing conversion [C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\intern\ghost\bf_intern_ghost.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\xmemory(784,1): error C1060: compiler is out of heap space [C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\extern\mantaflow\extern_mantaflow.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\goo-engine\extern\mantaflow\preprocessed\conjugategrad.h(330,1): error C1060: compiler is out of heap space [C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\extern\mantaflow\extern_mantaflow.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\goo-engine\extern\mantaflow\preprocessed\fileio\mantaio.cpp(168,1): error C2471: cannot update program database 'C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\lib\Release\extern_mantaflow.pdb' [C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\extern\mantaflow\extern_mantaflow.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\ostream(87,1): error C1060: compiler is out of heap space [C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\extern\mantaflow\extern_mantaflow.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\lib\win64_vc15\openVDB\include\openvdb\tree\LeafNode.h(1041,1): error C1060: compiler is out of heap space [C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\intern\cycles\scene\cycles_scene.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\goo-engine\extern\mantaflow\preprocessed\fluidsolver.cpp(57,1): error C1060: compiler is out of heap space [C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\extern\mantaflow\extern_mantaflow.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\lib\win64_vc15\tbb\include\tbb\tbb_machine.h(715,1): error C1060: compiler is out of heap space [C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\extern\mantaflow\extern_mantaflow.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\goo-engine\extern\mantaflow\preprocessed\fluidsolver.h(197): fatal  error C1002: compiler is out of heap space in pass 2 [C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\extern\mantaflow\extern_mantaflow.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\xstring(4840): fatal  error C1002: compiler is out of heap space in pass 2 [C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\extern\mantaflow\extern_mantaflow.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\goo-engine\extern\mantaflow\preprocessed\fluidsolver.h(197): fatal  error C1002: compiler is out of heap space in pass 2 [C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\extern\mantaflow\extern_mantaflow.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\goo-engine\intern\cycles\scene\volume.cpp(779,1): error C1060: compiler is out of heap space [C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\intern\cycles\scene\cycles_scene.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\lib\win64_vc15\tbb\include\tbb\parallel_for.h(201,73): error C1060: compiler is out of heap space [C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\extern\mantaflow\extern_mantaflow.vcxproj]
cl : command line  error D8040: error creating or communicating with child process [C:\Users\Aashu\Documents\gooEngine\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\extern\mantaflow\extern_mantaflow.vcxproj]
    1 Warning(s)
    14 Error(s)
```

Everything was going fine but at this point it failed 2 times do anyone knows about it help me .